# Using 'grep' in nested if-statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I'm still finding my way around bash scripting so please bear with me.
At the moment I am trying to write a script that checks a few on a server.
Once check is to see if the GPU driver has is the latest version.

However regardless of the installed GPU driver on the server, the script returns *GPU is not upgraded*

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

######################################################
#GENERAL VARIABLES
GPU_DRIVER=270.41.19
######################################################

#Checking if Packsges are Installed

if [ $(uname -r) != $KERNEL_VERSION ]

then

echo "Kernel is not Upgraded"
#INSTALL KENRENL!
#REBOOT!
    else if [ ! $(nvidia-smi -q |grep -q $GPU_DRIVER) ]

    then

    echo "GPU is not Upgraded"

            else if [ $(cat /usr/ort/build_number) != $CODE_RELEASE ]

            then
            echo "Code Release526 Has not Been Installed"

            fi
    fi
fi
```

I would like to know why the condition in the if-statement does not apply?

NOTE: 
The output of the *nvidia-smi* looks similar to below:

```
:~/script$ nvidia-smi -q|grep Driver
Driver Version                  : 270.41.19
Driver Model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to test whether a `grep` succeeded or failed. That does not require `[...]` or `$(...)`. You merely need to execute the `grep`. Contrary to popular belief, `[` is not part of the `if` statement syntax; it is a bash command which succeeds or fails based on the evaluation of a conditional expression. (Usually, you would want to use `[[`, which is a better conditional evaluator.) The `if` statement is followed by a series of ordinary bash statements; followed by the keyword `then`. If the last statement succeeds, the `then` branch is taken; otherwise the `else` branch is taken.

Change

```
else if [ ! $(nvidia-smi -q |grep -q $GPU_DRIVER) ]
```

to

```
elif ! nvidia-smi -q | grep -q -F "$GPU_DRIVER"; then
```

(And the `elif` will remove the need for the `fi` matching that `if`.)

Aside from removing the `test` built-in (`[`), I fixed a couple of other things:

- `grep` normally expects patterns to be regexes. In a regex, a <kbd>.</kbd> matches any character. I think you are looking for a precise match, so I added the `-F` flag.
- And I put quotes around the `$GPU_DRIVER`, just in case.

To explain the `if ... then ... elif ... fi` syntax, here's the entire `if` statement:

```
if [[ $(uname -r) != $KERNEL_VERSION ]]; then
    echo "Kernel is not Upgraded"
    #INSTALL KENRENL!
    #REBOOT!
elif ! nvidia-smi -q |grep -q -F "$GPU_DRIVER"; then
    echo "GPU is not Upgraded"
elif [[ $(cat /usr/ort/build_number) != $CODE_RELEASE ]]; then
    echo "Code Release526 Has not Been Installed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The grep -q does't return/print anything. It actually sets the return value as 0 or 1. You can check this using $?. So effectively your if statement becomes

```
[ ! $() ]
```

The $() returns false always. This results in the behavior you have defined.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense now. How do I change this? When I take the -q out, I get an error saying 'too many arguments'. Is there a way of checking the output of nvidia-smi?